# Unterschied zwischen „Vermeiden Sie, …“ oder „Vermeiden Sie es, …“

Tags: verb-usage, infinitive

Der ganze Satz lautet:

> Bitte vermeiden Sie (es), Dateianhänge von Spam-E-Mails zu öffnen.

Ich tendiere eher zu der Version mit *es,* aber ich kann nicht erklären, warum. Intuitiv würde ich eher *es vermeiden* verwenden, wenn ein Verb folgt (z.B. es vermeiden zu lachen) und *vermeiden*, wenn ein Substantiv folgt (z.B. Spam vermeiden).

Die gleiche Frage stelle ich mir bei:

> Wir helfen Unternehmen (dabei), ihre Arbeitsabläufe zu optimieren.

*Dabei* oder nicht? Ist vielleicht ein anderer Fall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Der Fall mit *bitte vermeiden Sie (es)* liegt bei mir gefühlsmäßig, ohne, dass ich eine genauere Erklärung bieten könnte, folgendermaßen:

Ich verwende das *es*, wenn ein vollständiger Nebensatz folgt.

> Bitte vermeiden Sie es, Dateianhänge von Spam-EMails zu öffnen.
>   Bitte vermeiden Sie es, auf den frisch gesäten Teil des Rasens zu treten.

Wohl gemerkt funktionieren diese Sätze aber auch ohne das *es*! Ich lasse das *es* weg, wenn kein Nebensatz folgt:

> Bitte vermeiden Sie das Öffnen unbekannter Dateianhänge.
>   Bitte vermeiden Sie das Betreten des frisch gesäten Rasens.

Diese Sätze funktionieren nur ohne das *es*!

Im Gegensatz dazu sehe ich den Fall mit *dabei* so, dass das *dabei* optional ist und eigentlich immer eingefügt/weggelassen werde kann.

Answer (score 2):

Einige Verben lassen sich mit Infinitiven ergänzen, andere weniger. Unter denjenigen, die sich ergänzen lassen, gibt es die Modalverben, denen der Infinitiv unangeschlossen folgt, und Vollverben, denen ein Infinitiv mit *zu* folgen muss. Beispiele:

> Ich lasse dich *gehen* (Modalverb)
>
> Ich bitte dich *zu gehen* (Vollverb)
>
> <strike>Ich erwarte von dir zu gehen</strike> Infinitivergänzung nicht möglich; stattdessen:
> Ich erwarte, dass du gehst. (Nebensatz)
> Ich erwarte dein Gehen. (Substantiviert)

*Helfen* gehört meines Erachtens zur Kategorie der Vollverben, die mit Infinitiven erweiterbar sind. Demnach wäre die folgende Formulierung korrekt:

> Wir helfen Unternehmen, ihre Arbeitsabläufe zu optimieren.

Was allerdings nicht heißt, dass die andere Form falsch wäre. Denn ein Objekt wird an *helfen* mit *bei* angefügt:

> Ich helfe dir *bei der Arbeit* — Ich helfe dir *dabei*

---

Etwas anders gelagert ist die Situation bei *vermeiden.* Dieses Verb erlaubt nach meinem Sprachgefühl *keine* Infinitivergänzungen sondern nur Objekte oder Nebensätze. Demnach muss ein Bezugswort – in deinem Fall *es* – eingefügt werden, wenn ein Infinitiv direkt angeschlossen werden soll.

> Bitte vermeiden Sie **es,** Dateianhänge zu öffnen.

Wird jedoch umformuliert und aus dem Infinitiv ein Substantiv (mithin ein Objekt) gemacht, muss das *es* entfallen:

> Bitte vermeiden Sie das Öffnen von Dateianhängen.